# How to send a parameter over http request using an anchor tag

Tags: servlets, anchor, httprequest, http-request-parameters

I want to send a parameter value over http using `<a>` tag but I do not want it to be set in the `href` attribute.

Is there a way to do just that so that I could receive that value on the server side?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  You could either use a hidden field (preferred) or a custom attribute although the html wouldn't technically be valid.

Comment: why not send it via a $_POST variable?

Comment: @Keith & @Zanrok: I just need to send an information to the server about the type of link clicked based on which I need a form to be displayed. Can't use the POST request there because I am using `href` to setting up a form and I would like to use the same URL for processing(POST) request as well. I would like to have a valid HTML for the same to be done. And I don't want that type-of-link-clicked information to be sent to the server in the `href` attribute.

Comment: The POST approach should work fine for you if you give the type-of-link form a post variable that doesn't appear in the main form. Then the server can display the form if that variable is present, and otherwise process the form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Either* use JS to submit a (hidden) form.

```html
<form id="foo" method="post" action="servletURL">
    <input type="hidden" name="yourParamName" value="yourParamValue" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('foo').submit(); return false;">link</a>
```

*Or* use CSS to style the default submit button to look like a link.

```html
<form id="foo" method="post" action="servletURL">
    <input type="hidden" name="yourParamName" value="yourParamValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="link" class="link" />
</form>
```

with

```css
input[type=submit].link {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: visible;
}
```